# .htaccess: автоматически изменять Url

Tags: apache, php, codeigniter

Привет всем.

У меня есть такой линк - `www.example.com/`. Я хочу, чтобы, когда кто-то заходил на сайт, линк автоматически был таким - `www.example.com/en`

Пока .htaccess такой:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|uploads|js|css|help|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|doc)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

(CodeIgniter ,хочу многоязычный сайт).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(CodeIgniter ,хочу многоязычный сайт)
Тогда тебе нужно поместить в переменную пользователя переменную $lang
на главной странице  www.example.com/index.php
сделать проверку и инклуд на папку с языком т.е.:

```
if(isset($lang)){
include("/".$lang."/index.php")
```

или же просто сделать папку lang там создать файлы ru.inc en.inc и т.д. а в них:

```
$lang=array(
"0" => "Введенные пароли не совпадают!",
"1" => "Пароль должен состоять из лат. букв или/и цифр!"
)
```

тогда вывод этого текста будет:

```
echo"Ошибка: ".$lang[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое значение с какого адреса, второе значение куда.

```
Redirect www.example.com/ www.example.com/en/

Redirect www.example.com/index.php www.example.com/en/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

То  же  самое   можно  сделать обычной функцией `header()`